I missed an access to MySQL root account
I missed an access to my root account in MySQL. I can't see my databases and create new databases.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root ERROR 2003
(HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)

net stop MySQL80

cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

// open another promplt window
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
mysql -u root

//output

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root ERROR 2003
(HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)


--skip-networking disables IP connection. Edit my.ini, set client for named pipes or shared memory (on Windows) or Unix socket files (on Unix) connection. Or use explicit --skip-networking=OFF.

Chapter 4 Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems
